# PostgreSQL separate User for Replication?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-11

I wanted to know why there is a need to create a separate user specifically for replication (User with REPLICATION privileges) or can i use a superuser to do the same?

I have a PostgreSQL 11 DB running which has one primary user (who is the superuser). A webapp connects to the DB using the same superuser. Now, I need to replicate this DB to a slave. Creating a new DB user (for replication or any other purpose) is a huge security issue/deal for our customers. I wanted to know if it is okay for me to replicate using the same superuser OR is there a need to create a replication user (with REPLICATION privilege). If a separate replication user is needed, can you please explain why?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently your customer is not really concerned about security, because "*A webapp connects to the DB using the same superuser*" is a **really**, really bad idea and a **much** greater security risk than creating a second user.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that a `superuser` can do that a `replication` user cannot do.  While the replication user is a very privileged role, it cannot do things like create/drop other superusers or install/use certain extensions.  If you do a `grep` on the source code, you can see:

```
$ grep "must be superuser to" -inr * | wc -l
     698
$ grep "must be superuser or replication role to" -inr * | wc -l
      37
```

Even though a replication role is highly privileged, it must not be mistaken for a superuser role.  Creating a superuser role needs to be very carefully considered, and given only to those who can be trusted with the responsibility.